# Different system call ID's responsible for calling different functions on different versions of OS

Tags: windows, system-calls

The same value of system call IDs on different versions of OS's are responsible for calling the different kernel functions. So when we use an executable file that was using during the era of Windows XP on Windows 7,why does the whole application work correctly?

Comment: Applications that use the NT API do not make direct system calls. They link to a stub function in a system library that in turn makes the system call, such as the `Nt` prefixed functions that are exported by ntdll.dll and the `NtUser` and `NtGdi` prefixed functions that are exported by win32u.dll (previously user32.dll). There are equivalent `Zw` prefixed exports, but in user mode there's no difference between them and using the `Nt` names is preferred.

Comment: That said, unless an application has a good reason (e.g. it's a user-mode service that's tightly coupled with a driver), I think it should prefer the Windows API over low-level system calls. IMO, if `CreateFileW` does the job, then use it. Only use `NtCreateFile` or `NtOpenFile` if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1):

Windows provides a large set of DLLs some of which act as thin (or sometimes not so thin) wrappers around system calls.

When the system call IDs change between different Windows versions, so do those DLLs.

But you import e.g. `CloseHandle()` from `kernel32.dll` by its name and so you don't see the change and things just work (that is, if we don't account for bugs and bug fixes that change the behavior that your program may have unfortunate dependencies on).

Comment: `CloseHandle` is a WINAPI call, not a system call. It implements added behavior such as supporting the standard I/O pseudohandles such as `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`, for which it additionally clears the process `StandardInput` handle in the PEB process parameters, and then closes the real file handle via the `NtClose` system call. It's calls such as `NtClose` that the OP is talking about. For example, in x64, the `NtClose` stub function in ntdll.dll moves the handle value to register r10; loads the system call number in register rax; and issues a `syscall` instruction to switch to kernel mode.

Comment: @eryksun You mention a more direct example, but not a different mechanism.

Comment: On XP the ID 0x11B9 is responsible for calling function NtGdiFullscreenControl,but on Windows 7 it's responsible for calling function NtGdiDdUpdateOverlay.
You mean both of them have the same functionality while they have different names? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Farshid, no, when we call `NtGdiFullscreenControl` in user mode, we're calling a stub function that's compiled with the system call number for that function in the given version of Windows, which varies. Once we transition to kernel mode via `syscall` (or via `int 0x2E` in an x86 32-bit build of Windows), the kernel's `NtGdiFullscreenControl` function is looked up in the system-call table -- in this case the extended table that has win32k.sys functions.

Comment: @eryksun, I investigated in an executable using Ollydbg.It displays the ID of the function instead of name.regardless of the version of the OS,This ID always remains fixed.Since the program has been compiled once and then used on every version of OS,how is it possible to change the functionality of a function during run time? In another expression,when the control arrives at the instruction MOV EAX,11B9 and then switch to kernel mode by MOV EDX,7FFE0300 & CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX],how is it detected and which of the functions NtGdiFullscreenControl or NtGdiDdUpdateOverlay should be substituted?

Comment: @Farshid In the past, it was common to import functions from DLLs either by their names or by their ordinal numbers (nowadays it's probably mostly or only by name). Those ordinal numbers would not change, but they are not syscall IDs, which can and do change. So, as long as you import instead of invoking syscalls directly, things should just work. Because the DLLs use the same syscall IDs as in the kernel, they match one another, they must. I don't know what's not to understand here.